# arcpy Union_analysis general function failure problem

Tags: arcpy, union

As part of a longer script, I use this code:

```
import arcpy, os

Polygon = r"pathtoashapefile.shp"
workspace = r"path_to_a_folder"
output = os.path.join(workspace, "test.shp")
arcpy.Union_analysis(Polygon, output, "ALL", "#", "GAPS")
```

and I get the error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 563, in Union
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

And this is a super frustrating error because it gives me no additional information.  I am only unioning with one polygon shapefile because I want to see overlaps between polygons within the shapefile.  I have tried all of the following:

putting Polygon in a list like: `[Polygon]`

Putting Polygon in a list like: `[Polygon, "#"]`

putting Polygon in a string formatted: `string = '"%s" #' % Polygon`

I have checked that Polygon has data in it and is not null.  I have checked that the path to Polygon and to workspace are valid.  I have not gotten any error other than the 'line 563' error in all of my attempts.

Comment: mmm the union tool might require the layer to be a feature layer

Comment: I've gotten union to work with shapefiles before in the actual tool, why would it be different for a script?

Comment: I could not give a definite reason why. but to use a tool like select by location in arcpy, the inputs must be feature layers

Comment: Union does not need feature layers but what we need is a code snippet that works up to where you see this error and the line number where that fails.

Comment: I understand that more code can only help, but this is part of a script that is quite large and as I'm an employee at a private firm I know my company is okay with me asking questions here as long as I'm not divulging our code.  Is there a meta post I can read that'll give me some guidance on what to do when I have to sanitize my scripts due to this situation and how to to that properly?

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, this question will probably only ever get answered if we see more code. I took your code and ran it on some test data with overlapping polygons and it ran without error. So assuming this code is correct it would suggest something else is causing a problem. The immediate thoughts are that you have set an environment setting such as extent or workspace that is causing some sort of conflict?

Comment: What we need is as little additional code as possible to reproduce what you are describing - see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers

Comment: I wonder if Polygon is a reserved word, you could rename your variable as a test.

Comment: These may be worth reviewing: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22general+function+failure%22